# What's the proper way to create Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeMediaGalleryEntryInterface without objectmanager?

Tags: magento2.3.1

I can't find the factory for this data object. I don't see it in the generated folder, nor do i see any references online. What's the best way to create this in my module? aside from using `objectManager`.

```
 Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeMediaGalleryEntryInterface
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to inject the following with dependency injection `\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeMediaGalleryEntryInterfaceFactory`

Reference: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/0eb8677b0b4e35606032e856cc1ef7c80e68829f/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Media/ImageEntryConverter.php#L38